# Put video in iframe with 100% width and autoplay

Tags: html, css, iframe, video, vimeo

I currently have a vimeo video embedded into my website. (code below)

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/4415083?api=1;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=d01e2f&amp;autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

As you can see I have autoplay on, and it also resizes to full width using the code above. My problem is I have just created a video on wideo.co and I need it to react in exactly the same way as the vimeo iframe above. Below is my Wideo iframe, can somebody show me how as I have tried and tried but can not seem to get it right.

```
<iframe width="540" height="310" src="http://www.wideo.co/embed/7022711418637317834?height=300&width=500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: How it works here on SO is if someone gives you a answer, you "accept" it as a solution, or you comment on a particular answer until an adequate solution is reached... at which point you accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Full width videos are a bit tricky.  There's no one-size-fits-all, but here's the gist of it:

1. Create a wrapping DIV that has **percentage-based** `padding-top` (note: the value will change depending on your  situation - you need to play with this value, get a calculator, use dev tools... you'll figure it out).
2. Position `absolute` the iframe within the DIV, with a top and bottom set to 0
3. Set the iframe width and height to `auto`

Here's some code:

```
<style>
.video-wrapper {
    position: relative;

    /* 
     Play with this value until you get the right aspect ratio.
     Note: Percentage based padding is calculated by the width of the containing element.
     Note 2: This value will be different for every website and/or media query...
    */
    padding-top: 45%;
}

.video-wrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /* this will override the width=""/height="" properties defined on the iframe */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe src="..."  width="540" height="310"></iframe>
</div>
```

If you're lazy, you can also head over to [fitvidsjs](http://fitvidsjs.com/) which handles creating the wrapping DIV and calculating the padding for you.  It's a great piece of code and works quite nicely and does not require a calculator.  I can calculate padding faster than I can go download the latest fitvids, upload it to my server, and reference it in code... but that's me.

Comment: what about `autoplay=1` still videos can't be played?

Comment: Autoplay should still work if the provider supports it. HTML5 video supports autoplay, and so should most video hosting providers.

Answer (score 0):

Put the content in div and then add width="100%" to iframe code. Add autoplay back to code.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
<iframe src="http://www.wideo.co/embed/7022711418637317834?height=300&width=500&autoplay=1" width="100%" height="310" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Why? Can't see a problem. If you need to add other tags and descriptions to iframe - go for it, it does not brake code.

Comment: would it help to mention that I have it currently inside <li> tags

Comment: This code will not maintain the videos aspect ratio and will always only be 310px tall.  There are also two `width` attributes, which is just poor coding imo.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the original width.